# Can I block some users from seeing photos in Active Directory via Outlook?

Tags: exchange, outlook, pictures

I am using some custom code to upload staff photos into Active Directory. We also use Outlook 2010 which will download these photos and display them as people are reading and writing emails. I've heard some feedback that this is a great feature and there are some that don't like it and have demanded to have their photo removed. Fair enough, but it strikes me that these people are getting a free ride: they don't object to benefiting from learning to match names to faces, but don't want others to be able to recognise them.

Ideally I would like these people to be able to opt out, but for them to no longer be able to see anyone else's photos. Is there a way for them to do this?

I'm aware that this can be disabled in Outlook via File > Options > Contacts > Show User Photographs When Available, but they can just switch this back on again.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a group policy to the users opting out (filter to a security group; call it "Camera Shy").

If you've added the [MS Office templates](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18968), set it at:

> User > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Office > Microsoft Office 2010 > Microsoft Office 2010 > Contact Card > Do not display photograph

Or if not, then you'll want to set the reg key directly instead:

```
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\common\turnoffphotograph
```